# Positive value to negative and negative to positive in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to convert postive value to negative and negative to positive and if its 0 then leave as it is. Im able to do it in sql, just need to know if there is any better way/alternate way to do it?

```
create table test_tab 
(a number);

insert into test_tab values (10);
insert into test_tab values (-10);
insert into test_tab values (0);
insert into test_tab values (10.15);
insert into test_tab values (-10.15);

select a , decode(sign(a),-1,abs(a),1,-abs(a),0) "changed value" from test_tab;
```

Database Oracle - 11g

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about multiplying with -1 ?

```
select a
,      -1 * a "changed value"
from   test_tab;
```

Answer (score 8):

how about just putting a negative sign

```
SELECT - -15 as inverse;

-->15

SELECT  -15 as inverse;

-->-15
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using subtraction:

```
SELECT 0 - a "changed value"
from test_tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a , decode(sign(a),-1,abs(a),1,-abs(a),0) -a from test_tab;
```

that's all you need

Comment: I know this option, i was looking for alternative ways